# How to compare two javascript arrays and count the differences

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, compare

I was working on an exercism.io and couldn't find a solid answer to compare two javascript arrays and count the differences. Here is one example that works; I hope it helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
var DNA = function(input){
  this.input = input;

  this.hammingDistance = function(letters){
    var split_input = input.split(''),
    split_letters = letters.split(''),
    length = Math.min(input.length, letters.length),
    countNotMatched = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
      if (split_letters[i] !== split_input[i]){
        countNotMatched = countNotMatched + 1;
      }
    }
    return countNotMatched;
  };
};
```